# Creating the date parameter in ssrs cube,getting the invalid token error

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to generate an SSRS report in tabular Cube and I'm not familiar with the DAX language. When I create the `year` and `month` parameters in the query, I get the following error:

> Query(1,19) the following syntax error occured during parsing: Invalid token,Line 1, Offset 19, ı.

My query:

```
DEFINE VAR TakvimYıl1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@TakvimYıl) = 1, IF(@TakvimYıl <> "", @TakvimYıl, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@TakvimYıl, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@TakvimYıl, 2), BLANK())
```

VAR TakvimYıl1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@TakvimYıl) > 1 && PATHITEM(@TakvimYıl, 1, 1) < 1

please help me:(

Comment: Is it possible the special characters in your query (such as ı) pose a problem?

Comment: i did not write any dax query and i did drag and drop on the ssrs report with cube.Also,a friend could be run but i cannot.